# Firebase Cloud messaging no sound/vibration

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using firebase to send notifications to my app(iOS and Android).
I'm not keen on using the `data` fields to send my notifications because for iOS `didReceiveRemoteNotification` doesn't get called when user has force quit the app. 
I've tried setting `"sound"` to all sorts of things including `default` and null but I'm not getting any sounds/vibrations on either devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was just a minor issue. I was placing the `sound` in root of json payload. While, it had to be inside the `notification` object. Firebase should really have a number of example payloads in their documentation.

Comment: So... what about vibration?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer firebase document, [table 2a](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Should put sound filed into notification payload, then it should work